# How to work out how far the bandwidth of each gaussian kernel used in my kernel density estimation reaches in my x axis

Tags: python, gaussian, kernel-density

I have applied kernel density estimation to my binary data of 300 points (xs = 300)  to create a continuous function.

```
density = gaussian_kde(plane_pos)
density.covariance_factor = lambda : .05
density._compute_covariance()
density_p = density(xs)
```

I want to know how the bandwidth, here calculated by .covariance_factor, relates the the dimensions of the x axis. Does each kernel used here have a width from end to end of how many days? How do I work this out?

Answer (score 0):

The bandwidth returned by `density.covariance_factor()` will only give you a scaled version. To properly scale it to your data, you should multiply this value by the standard deviation of your data. 
`import numpy
bw =  density.covariance_factor()*numpy.std(plane_pos)`

NOTE: Depending on how you want to define ''bandwidth'', you may want to multiply this by 2 (or not).